# Bootstrap 3.1.1 less in ASP.NET MVC 5 have error with EnableOptimizations in true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, less, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a project in "ASP.NET MVC 5" and use "less" for "bootstrap 3.1.1", and I use the following libraries for files less and min this:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Core/
http://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Less/
http://www.nuget.org/packages/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core/
http://www.nuget.org/packages/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie/
http://www.nuget.org/packages/MsieJavaScriptEngine/

and I have de similar proyect in MVC 4, but in MVC 5 when I set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations` in `true` like this:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

the following error occurs, does not interpret files "less" with variables, for example the error is:

```
Error type: Name
Message: variable @font-family-base is undefined
File: /Content/bootstrap/scaffolding.less
Line number: 29
Column number: 15
Source error:

Line 28: body {
Line 29:   font-family: @font-family-base;
-----------------------^
Line 30:   font-size: @font-size-base;
```

but if I include/import the file with vars in `/Content/bootstrap/scaffolding.less`:

```
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";
```

the error doesn't happen, and the error proceeds to the next file.

**Edit**

Now the same thing happens to me but with ASP.NET MVC 4, these are the libraries that I have installed by nuget. I don't understand what the problem is or if something happens with compatibly:

```
<package id="AjaxMin" version="5.6.5100.19204" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="AngularJS.Core" version="1.2.16" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="BundleTransformer.Core" version="1.8.17" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="BundleTransformer.Less" version="1.8.14" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax" version="1.8.15" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="FontAwesome" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core" version="0.9.5" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie" version="0.9.5" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="jQuery" version="1.10.2" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Modernizr" version="2.7.2" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="MsieJavaScriptEngine" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Twitter.Bootstrap.Less" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net40" />
```

web.config:

```
<sectionGroup name="bundleTransformer">
    <section name="core" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Configuration.CoreSettings, BundleTransformer.Core" />
    <section name="less" type="BundleTransformer.Less.Configuration.LessSettings, BundleTransformer.Less" />
  <section name="microsoftAjax" type="BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax.Configuration.MicrosoftAjaxSettings, BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax" />
</sectionGroup>
<sectionGroup name="jsEngineSwitcher">
    <section name="core" type="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.Configuration.CoreConfiguration, JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core" />
</sectionGroup>

...

<handlers>
  <add name="LessAssetHandler" path="*.less" verb="GET" type="BundleTransformer.Less.HttpHandlers.LessAssetHandler, BundleTransformer.Less" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />


...

<bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">
  <core>
    <css defaultMinifier="MicrosoftAjaxCssMinifier">
      <minifiers>
        <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
        <add name="MicrosoftAjaxCssMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax.Minifiers.MicrosoftAjaxCssMinifier, BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax" />
      </minifiers>
      <translators>
        <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
        <add name="LessTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Less.Translators.LessTranslator, BundleTransformer.Less" />
      </translators>
    </css>
    <js defaultMinifier="MicrosoftAjaxJsMinifier">
      <minifiers>
        <add name="NullMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Minifiers.NullMinifier, BundleTransformer.Core" />
        <add name="MicrosoftAjaxJsMinifier" type="BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax.Minifiers.MicrosoftAjaxJsMinifier, BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax" />
      </minifiers>
      <translators>
        <add name="NullTranslator" type="BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.NullTranslator, BundleTransformer.Core" enabled="false" />
      </translators>
    </js>
  </core>
  <less useNativeMinification="false" ieCompat="true" strictMath="false" strictUnits="false" dumpLineNumbers="None">
    <jsEngine name="MsieJsEngine" />
  </less>
</bundleTransformer>
<jsEngineSwitcher xmlns="http://tempuri.org/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Configuration.xsd">
  <core>
    <engines>
      <add name="V8JsEngine" type="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8.V8JsEngine, JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8" />
      <add name="MsieJsEngine" type="JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie.MsieJsEngine, JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie" />
    </engines>
  </core>
</jsEngineSwitcher>
```

**Edit 05-24-14**

BundleConfig.cs part of Css config:

```
CssTransformer cssTransformer = new CssTransformer();
NullOrderer nullOrderer = new NullOrderer();

Bundle cssBundle = new CustomStyleBundle(BundleName.Css);
cssBundle.Include("~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.less");
cssBundle.Include("~/Content/font-awesome.css");
cssBundle.Include("~/Content/site.less");
cssBundle.Transforms.Add(cssTransformer);
cssBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
bundles.Add(cssBundle);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this, in `BundleConfig.cs` the following configuration does not resolve `less` files correctly. maybe they need to add some additional property, but it does not work.

this is the problem, if this option removes the `less` files are processed correctly.

```
//CssTransformer cssTransformer = new CssTransformer();
NullOrderer nullOrderer = new NullOrderer();

Bundle cssBundle = new CustomStyleBundle(BundleName.Css);
cssBundle.Include("~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.less");
cssBundle.Include("~/Content/font-awesome.css");
cssBundle.Include("~/Content/site.less");
//cssBundle.Transforms.Add(cssTransformer);
cssBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
bundles.Add(cssBundle);
```

I not know what the right settings for "Transforms", but removing it solved my problem and the file is generated correctly and min.

Comment: I wish I had seen this question 8 hours ago... I have tried so many things... and finally it's this simple.  Anyway, I'm glad you posted the answer - thanks

Comment: This is because the `CustomStyleBundle` class already contains an instance of the `CssTransformer` or `StyleTransformer` class.
In your case, transformations from the `CssTransformer` or `StyleTransformer` class apply twice, which leads to errors.
All of these points are described in the [“Examples of usage”](https://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples%20of%20usage) section of documentation.

Comment: @AndreyTaritsyn Thanks for the comment. It is useful for me